# Is Boston bombing victim Jeff Bauman double-amputee soldier Nick Vogt?

Tags: terrorism, boston-marathon-bombings

From ['Disgusting' Facebook group called 'Dzhokhar Tsarnaev is innocent' attracts more than 11,000 fans worldwide](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2313303/Dzhokhar-Tsarnaev-innocent-Facebook-page-attracts-11-000-fans-worldwide.html#ixzz2RHhlTORU)

> Others believe the iconic image of Jeff Bauman in a wheelchair,
>   bloodied with his femur protruding through what was left of his thigh,
>   actually shows double-amputee soldier Nick Vogt, who survived an
>   encounter with an IED in Afghanistan a few years after his graduation
>   from the U.S. military Academy at West Point.
>
> Bauman and Vogt share certain resemblances, and on that basis the
>   conspiracy theorists conclude they are one and the same, with Vogt
>   playing the role of volunteer 'victim,' complete with a bottle of fake
>   blood discarded at his feet.
>
> 'Was Nick Vogt acting?' one asked in a note attached to a photo too
>   grisly to show.
>
> 'You think that's enough blood for 2 lost legs?' came a reply. 'When
>   they took another photo he was lying on the ground, pretending he was
>   badly injured.' 'I want to believe it's real,' chimed in a third, 'but
>   damn, that blood just looks like someone spilled a can of red paint.'

Is Jeff Bauman actually Nick Vogt?

Comment: Isn't "boston-marathon-bombings" kinda unnecessary tag, since this is just a temporary event, that probably wont be  thought much of in a year or so? Doesn't terrorism cover it enough?

Comment: there is [9-11] tag, same logic applies

Comment: I don't see how this question would be answerable right now, given that *"Neither Vogt nor his family has dignified the accusation with a response"*. I theory you could run facial recognition software on pictures of both, but that isn't very reliable.

Comment: I thought a newspaper already debunked this by showing that Nick Voght was nowhere near Boston on that day...

Comment: @vartec human brain is still the best facial recognition machine, a computer just has better speed for less accuracy

Comment: @vartec this thing falls in the same line as the 9/11 conspiracy theories, so is related to that :)

Comment: @sklivvz IMO, "Is Jeff Bauman an actor?" would mean that that the bombing victim is Jeff Bauman, and that he's also an actor. "Is Jeff Bauman actually an actor?" would mean that what is claimed to be Jeff Bauman isn't Bauman, but is Vogt instead. Did you do this edit because of http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/445/104 ?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, how about this title?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed looks ok.

Comment: and better than "terrorism" would be "crime"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nick Vogt is missing his left pinky finger, [here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7zdgmfQUMs&sns=fb) where he's doing pushups and it's clearly seen that he has only 4 fingers on his left hand:

[image: screen shot]

Jeff Bauman has all his fingers on the left hand. Here is a picture from a visit by Bradly Cooper, Jeff is holding a ball with his left hand, and it's clearly seen that he has all 5 fingers (one of them is white because of medical instrument):

[image: pic]

[source](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/showbiz/news/a474503/bradley-cooper-visits-boston-bombing-survivor-in-hospital-picture.html)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  Answers here [are expected to be backed by references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). Could you update your answer to provide sources for the claim that Nick Vogt is missing a finger, but Bauman is not?

Comment: Rather than everyone of us talking to soldiers, etc., it would be more efficient (and rather more useful for a Q&A site) if you found one who documented some evidence, and we could all read that without bothering anyone.

Comment: I served 6 years in the military as an xray tech and currently work  at an army hospital sorry I did not mention that. I have written no articles about what I have seen to site them.